# iMacros: content extraction issues

Tags: imacros

I was just wondering if someone could help me out a bit here?

This is my current script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:create_new_folder CONTENT=TEST_{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=ID:selall CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:to_folder CONTENT=%3821
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:to_folder_move
```

I want to fully automate this.

Modifying the loop based on the content works:

```
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:to_folder CONTENT=%382{{!LOOP}}
```

But this would run into two problems:

1. When it reaches 10 folders, the content ID would change to =%383X
2. The digit I want defining the folder is separate to the content ID and I definitely want it to match the loop. The reason I stated this as an issue, because I considered using the SET !LOOP function but that lead to a load of other problems.

So what I'm thinking is that I would like to check the Content ID of the folder I create, place it into a variable then set it to match.

Something like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !VAR1 {{EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:create_new_folder CONTENT=TEST_{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=*
**SOMEHOW EXTRACT THE ID**
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=ID:selall CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:to_folder CONTENT=%{{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:F1 ATTR=NAME:to_folder_move
```

So how would I go about getting that ID to extract? I can't program like at all, so I'm sorry if my thinking is a bit flawed here.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Oh, and I'm using FireFox in case that has any form of relevance.

Comment: You have to use JavaScript scripting.

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind giving me a little more guidance here? I can't actually program in any language at all so I'm not quite sure where I'd start.

Comment: Hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: You must use scripting.  Python is an easy language to start programming litle scripts for imacros.  I use it, and it's very quickly to code. Try [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)